# Adding navigation arrows to Wordpress Woocommerce - Mobile?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I followed [this tutorial](https://wpbeaches.com/add-navigation-arrows-in-woocommerce-product-gallery-slider/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20add%20Navigation%20Arrows,a%20few%20more%20configurable%20options.&text=The%20flexslider%20has%20some%20more%20options%20you%20can%20manipulate%E2%80%A6) to add navigation arrows to the product photos on my Wordpress Woocommerce store.

They say to add the following code to functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options', 'sf_update_woo_flexslider_options' );
/** 
 * Filer WooCommerce Flexslider options - Add Navigation Arrows
 */
function sf_update_woo_flexslider_options( $options ) {

    $options['directionNav'] = true;

    return $options;
}
```

And the following code to the CSS file:

```
ul.flex-direction-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;}

li.flex-nav-prev {float: left;}
li.flex-nav-next {float: right;}
a.flex-next {visibility:hidden;}
a.flex-prev {visibility:hidden;}

a.flex-next::after {
    visibility:visible;content: '\f054';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;   
    font-weight: bold;
}

a.flex-prev::before {
    visibility:visible;
    content: '\f053';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';   
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul.flex-direction-nav li a {
    color: #ccc;
}

ul.flex-direction-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.flex-direction-nav li a {
    color: #ccc;
}

ul.flex-direction-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It works really well on desktop, but when I load the mobile site the arrows aren't there, it just says "next" and "previous" underneath the photos instead. Is there any way to ensure the arrows show up on mobile?

Thanks.